# IntelliJ Plugin Development: A context item is shown in IDEA but not in WebStorm

Tags: java, intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

I am implementing an IntelliJ IDE plugin that is supposed to work in all Jetbrains IDEs.

I created an action which is declared like this:

```
<actions>
    <group id="MyGroup">
        <add-to-group group-id="EditorPopupMenu"/>
        <action class="my.pkg.MyAction" id="MyAction" text="My Text"/>
    </group>
</actions>
```

It is supposed to show up when a user opens a context menu while editing code.

**Problem:** While the corresponding context item is present in IDEA it is absent in WebStorm.

**Question:** Why the context item is not shown in WebStorm? How to ensure the plugin behaves the same way in all Jetbrains IDEs?

Answer (score 2):

Solved by adding the following dependency:

```
<idea-plugin>
    ...
    <depends>com.intellij.modules.lang</depends>
    ...
</idea-plugin>
```